# Why won't my background-size change in CSS?

Tags: css

[image]

The white box with the cut off form to the left is the background here.

I temporarily took out all other styling and this is all that is left (some of it is not mine):

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #69ce16;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 20%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    width: 50%;
}
```

I added the background size, repeat and position myself and even tried adjusting every other value there but nothing has worked. I used developer.mozilla.org for info on every single one of those css properties, so I have no idea why it won't center to the middle of that "grey" page, or anywhere I want it, and even trying to reduce its size/width has not worked.

Comment: Without your full code, it's hard to say, but don't assume the `body` element is filling the whole screen. It isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your width for example to

```
body{
   ...
   width: 50%;
   /* maybe add some height? */
   height: 500px;
}
```

Then you will see a change

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
    body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #69ce16;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: white;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 20%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    width: 80%;
    height:200px;
}</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you even read the css you have?

```
border: 1px solid #ced4da;
width: 50%;
```

you most certainly wouldn't wanna add paddings text-align, color on body...

anyways.

If you clean the body and html in your css, and add a wrapper div on the form you want with some css like this

```
.form-wrapper{
     background-color: red;
     margin: auto;
     width: 50%;
     border: 1px solid #ced4da;
     border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

It would achieve the look you want. I would suggest you take a look at [css docs](https://www.w3schools.com/css/)...

Comment: "you most certainly wouldn't wanna add paddings text-align, color on body" If it's applicable, why not? I've been applying general styles to `body` since CSS was invented.

Comment: Cause it's not normal for others to understand unless they read your css. 
Generally, body would be to set a background color, margin: 0,  padding: 0, font family, antialiasing